# How can I click a drawable svg in TextinputEdittext?

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I have an svg on an textinputedittext. It is on the right side of the edittext. I want to click and get an action from it.

This is xml of edittexxt:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textinputlayout_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:endIconMode="custom"
                app:errorIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_icon_show_hide_svg"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/constraintlayout_login_editable_areas"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/constraintlayout_login_editable_areas"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edittext_login_username"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <com.example.android.custombutton.CustomEdittext
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_login_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="54dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
                    android:hint="Password"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

How can I click this: `@drawable/ic_icon_show_hide_svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/textinputlayout_login"
       app:endIconMode="custom"
       app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_icon_show_hide_svg"
       ..>
```

Then you can define a clickListener with:

```
textinputlayout_login.setEndIconOnClickListener { 
    //do something 
}
```

For a password textfield you can also use the built-in feature `endIconMode="password_toggle"`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
```